# Correspondence between set of subspaces W and set of subspaces of V/K

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have a Linear Algebra question on Vector Spaces that I'm a bit stuck on.

Let K be a subspace of a vector space and $W \subseteq V$. Show that the assignment $W \mapsto W/K$ ($W/K \subseteq V/K$) defines 1-1 correspondence between the set of subspaces W of V with $K \subseteq W \subseteq V$ and the set of subspaces of V/K.

I was hoping someone would be able to give me some guiding help to get me started on it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For it to be one-to-one, it will have to be injective and surjective.

**Injective**: The only way for it to *fail* to be injective is if two subspaces $W_1$, $W_2$ get sent to the same $W'/K\subseteq V/K$. When would it be possible for this to happen? Why does that mean it's *not* possible in this case?

**Surjective**: Imagine we have some subset $U\subseteq V/K$. Can you think of a way to "go backwards" to get a subset $U'\subseteq V$ such that $U'/K = U$?

Comment: So for surjectivity I think I get it - couldn't we take for example K = {0} and U' = U and then U'/K = U? 
But for injectivity I'm still a little unsure about when this could happen. I think it's when the kernel is non-empty, but I'm not sure how I could prove that it is empty in this case.

Comment: @jamesmbcn we can't take $K$ as zero actually, as we want to think of $K$ as "fixed" here. Otherwise, we wouldn't be fully proving the theorem, as it's supposed to hold *whenever* $K\subseteq V$. We would be proving it *in the specific case* that $K = \{0\}$.

Injectivity is just showing that $w_1\neq w_2\implies f(w_1)\neq f(w_2)$. The contrapositive of this is $f(w_1) = f(w_2)\implies w_1 = w_2$. I think this is easier to prove. When are two things the same in the quotient? When they differ by an element in $K$.

Comment: @jamesmbcn So, for any particular pairs of *elements*, we have that $f(w_1) = f(w_2)\implies w_1 = w_2 + ck$, where $k\in K$.  We want to extend this basic result to show that for *the entire subspaces $W_1$ and $W_2$* that $f(W_1) \cong f(W_2)\implies W_1\cong W_2$. Can you see how we might do that?